# open a file from file system in browser spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to open an XML file located at path.

```
//opt/tomcat//webapps//ROOT//abc.xml
```

with url http://www.test.com/abc.xml in spring MVC

Comment: The answer is yes. If you want real help, post a real question, with the code, the expectations, the actual behavior, etc.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks, it solved my problem, i was not able to find the link its a dublicate

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to help.